# Scala 3. Context bound and type lambda

Tags: scala, types, scala-3

Learning Scala 3.

Notice type projection + context bound in `monadWriter`

```
trait Monoid[A] {
  def zero: A

  def append(a1: A, a2: A): A
}

trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def unit[A](a: A): F[A]

  def flatMap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]

  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] = {
    flatMap(fa)(a => unit(f(a)))
  }
}

  given monadWriter[W: Monoid]: Monad[({type l[x] = Writer[x, W]})#l] = new Monad[({type l[x] = Writer[x, W]})#l] {
    override def unit[A](a: A): Writer[A, W] =
      Writer(a, implicitly[Monoid[W]].zero)

    override def flatMap[A, B](fa: Writer[A, W])(f: A => Writer[B, W]): Writer[B, W] = {
      val fa2 = f(fa.v)
      Writer(fa2.v, implicitly[Monoid[W]].append(fa.w, fa2.w))
    }
  }
```

that code works ok.

**Question:** how can i refactor above code to Scala 3 type lambda syntax? How can I properly specify context bound to Monoid?

Below code fails to compile (unhappy about types in overrides):

```
  given monadWriter[A, W: Monoid]: Monad[[W]=>>Writer[A,W]] = new Monad[[W]=>>Writer[A,W]] {
    override def unit[A](a: A): Writer[A, W] =
      Writer(a, implicitly[Monoid[W]].zero)

    override def flatMap[A, B](fa: Writer[A, W])(f: A => Writer[B, W]): Writer[B, W] = {
      val fa2 = f(fa.v)
      Writer(fa2.v, implicitly[Monoid[W]].append(fa.w, fa2.w))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
given monadWriter[W: Monoid]: Monad[[x] =>> Writer[x, W]] = new Monad[[x] =>> Writer[x, W]]:
  override def unit[A](a: A): Writer[A, W] = ???
  override def flatMap[A, B](fa: Writer[A, W])(f: A => Writer[B, W]): Writer[B, W] = ???
```

or better

```
given [W: Monoid]: Monad[[x] =>> Writer[x, W]] with
  override def unit[A](a: A): Writer[A, W] = ???
  override def flatMap[A, B](fa: Writer[A, W])(f: A => Writer[B, W]): Writer[B, W] = ???
```

`summon[Monoid[W]]` should be instead of `implicitly[Monoid[W]]`.

Comment: Dmytro, virutal "cheers" :) , you keep educating me these weeks. I'm putting recently met type lambda into practice. I see where I was wrong. Can you explain me how `x` type param is kinda "hanging" in the air and is not linked to given part (i was trying to specify ALL type params at given side)? i don't get type wiring for `x`

Comment: asking about this hanging `x` because in my previous plays with type lambda (like partially applied type constructor) i had to denote partially applied (fixed type at `given` side) always...

Comment: @Max Not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "hanging"? Why don't ordinary (value-level) lambdas `x => foo(x, 42)` confuse you while type lamdas do? Do you understand the difference between `x` in `def bar(x: Int, y: String) = ???` and `x` in  `def bar(y: String) = baz(x => foo(x, 42))`?

Comment: Sorry, for this, now i see where i got confused in my previous plays: namely at places where I was __reusing__ same letter for type param: like here: `type CurriedStateTypeCtor[S] = [A] =>> State[S, A] ; given stateMonad[S]: Monad[CurriedStateTypeCtor[S]] with {...some use of A type...}` and indeed that A is independent type, and simply reused letter `type CurriedStateTypeCtor[S] = [Z] =>> State[S, Z] ; given stateMonad[S]: Monad[CurriedStateTypeCtor[S]] with {...some use of A type...}` . Jesus, what a mess

Comment: @Max Well, simple advice is try to avoid using the same identifier for different purposes. Feel free to start a new question if you're still feel confused.